# Read stock files, gets the candles sequence and makes a report - follow-up

Tags: c++, beginner

My first question: [Read, calculate, write](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/181636/read-calculate-write)

The only thing I kept is the function try-block.

This is still a work in progress, that's what I have done so far.

## Source:

```
// this program read stock files, gets the candles sequence and makes a report
// about the patterns it founds and how many times they appeared.
// this program reads files only having this fornat (or similar):
// yyyy.mm.dd,hh:mm,open,high,low,close,0\n
// where open - high - low - close are floating point.

#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace filesystem = std::experimental::filesystem::v1;

const std::map<std::string, std::vector<filesystem::path>>
get_files_by_symbol(const filesystem::path &directory);

const std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>>
get_candles_by_timeframe(const std::vector<filesystem::path> &symbol);

void get_candles_from_chart(const std::vector<filesystem::path> &symbol,
                            const time_t &rounder, const time_t &value,
                            const std::string &name,
                            std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>> &candles);

const std::time_t mkgmtime(const std::tm &tm, const time_t &shift);

const std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>
get_events(const int &candles_to_check, const std::vector<bool> &candles);

const std::string get_binary(const int &candles_current_position,
                             const int &candles_to_pass,
                             const std::vector<bool> &candles);

const long binary_to_decimal(long binary);

void write_report(const std::string &file, const int &candles_to_check,
                  const std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> &events);

int main() try {
  const filesystem::path data{"data"};
  filesystem::create_directory(data);
  const filesystem::path report{"report"};
  filesystem::create_directory(report);
  auto files_by_symbol(get_files_by_symbol(data));

  for (auto &symbol : files_by_symbol) {
    // some operating systems don't have ordered directory
    std::sort(symbol.second.begin(), symbol.second.end());
    const auto candles_by_timeframe{get_candles_by_timeframe(symbol.second)};

    for (const auto &candles : candles_by_timeframe) {
      const std::string output_file{report.string() + '/' + symbol.first + "_" +
                                    candles.first + ".csv"};

      for (int candles_to_check{2}; candles_to_check < 11; ++candles_to_check) {
        const auto events(get_events(candles_to_check, candles.second));
        write_report(output_file, candles_to_check, events);
        std::cout << candles_to_check << " candles's sequence - done" << '\n';
      }
      std::cout << output_file << " - done" << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
} catch (const std::exception &err) {
  std::cout << err.what() << '\n';
}

const std::map<std::string, std::vector<filesystem::path>>
get_files_by_symbol(const filesystem::path &directory) {
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<filesystem::path>> files_by_symbol;

  for (filesystem::path const &file :
       filesystem::directory_iterator(directory)) {
    files_by_symbol[file.filename().string().substr(7, 6)].push_back(file);
  }

  return files_by_symbol;
}

const std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>>
get_candles_by_timeframe(const std::vector<filesystem::path> &symbol) {
  std::map<std::string, long> timeframes{{{"h1", 3600}, {"d1", 86400}}};
  std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>> candles;

  for (const auto &timeframe : timeframes) {
    const std::string name{timeframe.first};
    const time_t value{timeframe.second};
    // in the data there can be leaps between minutes, so it rounds those.
    const time_t rounder{value >= 3600 ? 3600 : value};

    get_candles_from_chart(symbol, rounder, value, name, candles);

    std::cout << "timeframe : " << name << " - done" << '\n';
  }
  return candles;
}

void get_candles_from_chart(const std::vector<filesystem::path> &symbol,
                            const time_t &rounder, const time_t &value,
                            const std::string &name,
                            std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>> &candles) {
  for (const auto &current_file : symbol) {
    std::ifstream input(current_file, std::ios::binary);

    if (!input.is_open()) {
      throw std::runtime_error("INPUT - COULDN'T OPEN " +
                               current_file.string());
    }

    std::tm tm{0};
    input >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y.%m.%d,%H:%M,");

    while (!input.eof()) {
      const time_t shift{21600}; // H6 - to sync with metatrade
      const std::time_t datetime = mkgmtime(tm, shift) / rounder * rounder;
      std::string pending;
      std::getline(input, pending);
      const float open{std::stof(pending)};

      // second statment: the results are times, not in seconds instead they
      // are based on the timeframe rounded downward, when they are not equel
      // it means that a timeframe-time has passed between the datetime and
      // the last date retrieved, remember: mkgmtime return (ALWAYS) seconds
      // since epoch.
      while (input >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y.%m.%d,%H:%M,") &&
             mkgmtime(tm, shift) / value == datetime / value) {
        std::getline(input, pending);
      }

      const float close{std::stof(pending.erase(0, pending.rfind('.') - 1))};
      enum candle_color : const bool { green = 0, red = 1 };
      close >= open ? candles[name].push_back(green)
                    : candles[name].push_back(red);
    }
    std::cout << current_file << " - done" << '\n';
  }
}

const std::time_t mkgmtime(const std::tm &tm, const time_t &shift) {
  const int years{tm.tm_year};

  // check to prevent overflow
  if (years < 70 || years > 155) {
    std::ostringstream invalid_date;
    invalid_date << std::put_time(&tm, "%Y.%m.%d %H:%M");
    throw std::range_error("INVALID DATE : " + invalid_date.str());
  }

  const int days_per_months[12] = {-1,  30,  58,  89,  119, 150,
                                   180, 211, 242, 272, 303, 333};
  int total_days{(years - 70) * 365};
  const int month{tm.tm_mon};
  total_days += days_per_months[month]; // same as tm_yday
  total_days += tm.tm_mday;

  // check if this year is a leap year and if it is at least febrary
  if (((years % 4 == 0 && years % 100 != 0) || (years + 300) % 400 == 0) &&
      month > 1)
    ++total_days;

  // leap years (1900 - your_date) - 17 (leap years from 1900 - 1970)
  total_days += (years - 1) / 4 - (years - 1) / 100 + (years + 299) / 400 - 17;

  return (static_cast<std::time_t>(total_days * 86400 + tm.tm_hour * 3600 +
                                   tm.tm_min * 60 + shift));
}

const std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>
get_events(const int &candles_to_check, const std::vector<bool> &candles) {
  // size: the number of combination of a sequence of bool
  std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> events(std::pow(2, candles_to_check),
                                                  std::make_pair(0, ""));

  for (size_t candles_current_position{0};
       candles_current_position < candles.size() - candles_to_check + 1;
       ++candles_current_position) {
    // each sequence of bool is a binary number
    const auto binary{get_binary(candles_current_position,
                                 candles_current_position + candles_to_check,
                                 candles)};
    const auto decimal{binary_to_decimal(std::stol(binary))};
    events[decimal].first++;
    events[decimal].second = binary;
  }

  std::sort(events.begin(), events.end(),
            std::greater<std::pair<int, std::string>>());

  return events;
}

const std::string get_binary(const int &candles_current_position,
                             const int &candles_to_pass,
                             const std::vector<bool> &candles) {
  std::string binary{""};

  for (int index{candles_current_position}; index < candles_to_pass; ++index) {
    binary += std::to_string(candles[index]);
  }

  return binary;
}

const long binary_to_decimal(long binary) {
  long decimal{0};
  long base{1};

  while (binary > 0) {
    long rem{binary % 10};
    decimal += rem * base;
    base *= 2;
    binary /= 10;
  }

  return decimal;
}

void write_report(const std::string &file, const int &candles_to_check,
                  const std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> &events) {
  std::ofstream output(file, std::ios::app);

  if (!output.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("OUTPUT - COULDN'T OPEN " + file);
  }

  output << "CANDLES : " << candles_to_check << '\n';

  for (auto const &event : events) {
    output << event.second << "  ---  " << event.first << '\n';
  }
}
```

## What's new:

I made so that the program now can read more than just one timeframe at the time.

I splitted my main function in several other functions and I left just what I felt was needed for follow the flow. I rewrote the comments, I made so that I commented just what I felt needed an explanation.

Some may be trivia such as:

```
// each sequence of bool is a binary number
const auto binary{get_binary(candles_current_position,
                             candles_current_position + candles_to_check,
                             candles)};
```

That can be tricky and misunderstood so I pointed it out.

---

I rewrote some of my code and learned some new things and implemented them, such as:

```
if (!filesystem::is_directory(user_files_directory)) {
    filesystem::create_directory(user_files_directory);
}
```

[`create_directory`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/create_directory): If `p` already exists and is already a directory, the function does nothing (this condition is not treated as an error), so I don't need the `if` statement.

```
if (filesystem::is_empty(user_files_directory)) {
  std::string error{"USER FILES DIRECTORY (" + user_files_directory.string() +
                    ") IS EMPTY - FILL IT"};
  throw error;
}
```

This is not an error, if the directory is empty the program runs as usual.

```
// WE DIVIDE THE FILES IN THE FOLDER BY THE SYMBOL, SO WE THEN CAN CALL THEM
// BY THEIR PAIR
std::vector<std::vector<filesystem::path>> user_files_paths_by_symbol;
{
  // SOME SYSTEMS DON'T HAVE ORDERED DIRECTORY THEREFORE WE ORDER IT
  std::vector<filesystem::path> user_files_paths;
  std::copy(
      filesystem::begin(filesystem::directory_iterator(user_files_directory)),
      filesystem::end(filesystem::directory_iterator(user_files_directory)),
      std::back_inserter(user_files_paths));
  std::sort(user_files_paths.begin(), user_files_paths.end());
   std::string symbol{user_files_paths[0].filename().string().substr(7, 6)};
  int start_index{0};
  int index{-1};
  for (auto &file : user_files_paths) {
    index++;
    std::string filename_string{file.filename().string()};
     // THIS PROGRAM WORKS JUST WITH MT TYPE OF DATA
    if (filename_string.find("DAT_MT") == std::string::npos) {
      std::string error{filename_string + " - IS NOT A METATRADE FILE"};
      throw error;
    }
     if (filename_string.find(symbol) == std::string::npos) {
      std::vector<filesystem::path> row(user_files_paths.begin() +
                                            start_index,
                                        user_files_paths.begin() + index);
      user_files_paths_by_symbol.push_back(row);
      symbol = user_files_paths[index].filename().string().substr(7, 6);
      start_index = index;
    }
  }
   std::vector<filesystem::path> row(user_files_paths.begin() + start_index,
                                    user_files_paths.begin() + index + 1);
  user_files_paths_by_symbol.push_back(row);
}
```

This code is too messy and has too many thing going on. The file check isn't needed, the sorting will be done later, and the order things are just junk. I replaced that with the code below.

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<filesystem::path>> files_by_symbol;

for (filesystem::path const &file :
     filesystem::directory_iterator(directory)) {
  files_by_symbol[file.filename().string().substr(7, 6)].push_back(file);
}

return files_by_symbol;
```

---

I tried to make the variables/functions name more readable and I got rid off of all name_string, name_path, name_(same_typename)
 And some other small changes.

## Some questions:

Based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703743/8501047) I replace:

```
std::string binary_string{std::accumulate(
            candles.begin() + candles_current_position,
            candles.begin() + candles_current_position + candles_to_check,
            std::string{}, [](std::string &sequence, const bool &new_element) {
              return sequence + std::to_string(new_element);
            })};
```

with:

```
std::string binary{""};

for (int index{candles_current_position}; index < candles_to_pass; ++index) {
  binary += std::to_string(candles[index]);
}

return binary;
```

1. What do you think? Performance-wise are the same, but I feel like `std::accumulate` is too fancy.
2. Before each function should I make a brief explanation about what it does?
3. Now that I have a lot of function should I create a single header file and make for each function a cpp file? or should I make a header file for each cpp file?

How do I deal with huge functions parameters like this?

```
void get_candles_from_chart(const std::vector<filesystem::path> &symbol,
                            const time_t &rounder, const time_t &value,
                            const std::string &name,
                            std::map<std::string, std::vector<bool>> &candles)
```

I know that in this case I can return the map but it's annoying to handle. In other similar case how do I handle that? This is unpleasant to look at.

1. Is anything bad/wrong with the code?
2. Is my code clean? How can I make it clean/cleaner?
3. What do you think about the work done?
4. How can I improve my code? How you would improve it?

If you would like to test it: [Use this test-data](http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-data/?/metatrader/1-minute-bar-quotes). Those are bad data but they are free.